# How to make an input type="submit" from href?

Tags: html, css, input, types

I have this and need the same style for an `input type="submit"` or `"button"`. Is it possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

```css
a.dlbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  background-color: #4b4b4b;
 
}
a.dlbtn:hover,
a.dlbtn:focus {
  color: #fff;
  padding-right: 90px;
  background-color: #5381bf;
  border-color: #5381bf;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="dlbtn">Descarga<span class="details">.iso<span class="size">2.9 gb</span></span></a>
```

Comment: Paste your code in your question please

Comment: use <button type="submit">

Comment: http://jseditor.proyectosbds.com/atuvav/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

for the button and submit put the `class="dlbtn"`:

```
<input type="submit" class="dlbtn">
```

for button

```
<button name="xxxx" class="dlbtn">
```

Comment: class or id doesnt work in input type i think http://jseditor.proyectosbds.com/asuyim/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a button and input element with the `dlbtn` class:

```
<input class="dlbtn" type="submit" value="Submit">
<button class="dlbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Right now, your `dlbtn` class is restricted to `a` tags (such that, even when the class is set on the elements above, it is not applied):

```
a.dlbtn {[...]}
a.dlbtn:hover {[...]}
a.dlbtn:focus {[...]}
```

You can either add additional html tags to the css selector, allowing the class declaration to apply to `a`, `input` and `button` html tags with the `dlbtn` class set:

```
a.dlbtn, input.dlbtn, button.dlbtn {[...]}
a.dlbtn:hover, input.dlbtn:hover, button.dlbtn:hover {[...]}
a.dlbtn:focus, input.dlbtn:focus, button.dlbtn:focus {[...]}
```

Or you can remove the html tag restriction and apply the class to any html element with the 'dlbtn' class (like `<div class="dlbtn">[...]</div>`):

```
.dlbtn {[...]}
.dlbtn:hover {[...]}
.dlbtn:focus {[...]}
```

Just to warn you, both `input` and `button` come with standard styling provided by the browser. You might find another answer on StackOverflow that will speak to methods for overriding the standard styles (like using `-webkit-appearance:none` to handle some of Chrome's automatic styles for the input element).

**Edit**: Updated `<button>` type to read 'submit' per Leo Farmer.

Comment: Button type should be "submit" not "button" or it won't submit the form